# How to run rails2 app on passenger and apache2 in centos

Tags: ruby, passenger, ruby-on-rails-2

**I have an old Rails 2.0.1/Ruby 1.8.7 app it had run in a production environment on centos 6 using thin and appcahe2 server.But i need to run on Passenger and Apache2 server,is there any possibilities to run on it..?**

Thanks for Your Help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for below links to refer all steps to set up your application on passenger and Apache2. In those links, author shows setup of  application made with latest rails and ruby versions but you can change that as your requirement.

[Install Ruby on Rails with Apache and Passenger on CentOS 6](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-ruby-on-rails-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6/)

[How To Setup a Rails 4 App With Apache and Passenger on CentOS 6](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6)